# Particle Subject to Central Force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is a differential problem of a particle under a central force (i.e $F_\theta = 0$).
$$F_r = ma_r = m(\ddot r - r(\dot\theta)^2)$$
$$F_\theta = m(2\dot r \theta + r\ddot\theta)$$

Since F is a central force, $F_\theta = 0$, which means $\dot\theta = h/r^2$ where h is a constant.
Now F, the central force is given as $F= -k*m/r^2$
So, equating $F_r$ and F gives
$$\ddot r - h^2 /r^3 = -k/r^2$$
So the text I'm looking at they go about solving this differential by solving for r in terms of $\theta$, not in terms of time as it is given. So they do a substitution of $u = 1/r$ and differentiate r to get $\ddot r$.
$$\dot r = -\frac {1}{u^2} \frac {du}{dt} = -\frac {1}{u^2} \frac {du}{d\theta} \frac {d\theta}{dt} = -h \frac {du}{d\theta}$$
$$\ddot r = -h \frac {d^2u}{d\theta^2} \dot \theta = -h^2 u^2 \frac {d^2u}{d\theta^2}$$

Now, I was wondering how I can get r in terms of $\theta$ without the substitution, so I could solve directly $r(\theta)$ without doing the substitution. I am not sure if I am getting a proper differential, if someone could please verify that this is the differential it should be.

So I do instead:
$$\dot r = \frac {dr}{d\theta} \frac {d\theta}{dt}$$

Now this I'm not sure about:
$$\ddot r = \frac {d^2 r}{d\theta^2} \dot \theta \frac {d\theta}{dt} + \frac {d^2 \theta}{dt^2} \frac {dr}{d\theta}$$
Substituting into the original differential:
$$\ddot r - h^2 /r^3 = -k/r^2$$

Since $F_\theta = 0$, $\dot \theta = h/r^2$ and $\ddot \theta = (-2 \dot r \dot \theta)/r$
I substitute in and get:
$$\frac {d^2 r}{d\theta^2} - \frac {2 (\frac {dr}{d\theta})^2}{r} - r = -k* \frac {r^2}{h^2}$$

I don't think it's right. Please let me know if the differential is right.

Thank you.